# Solo ver una categoria de usuarios - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, users-roles, usercontrol

En internet esta lleno de métodos para limitar que solo puedan ver, editar o crear una categoría en Entradas. Yo necesito lograr lo mismo pero con usuarios.

Lo que quiero lograr es que un usuario solo pueda ver, editar y crear una categoría de un usuario.

No se si se puede hacer o de qué manera lograr esto.

Comment: hola, buscas algo como esto? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205423/restrict-frontend-view-to-post-author-and-administrator

Comment: Si, pero para usuarios y en el backend. No para las entradas.